# How to properly use EF Core to not create new junction table for every derived type?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am currently having an inheritance structure in EntityFrameworkCore which looks like this:

Product as Base class

Underneath this product there can be a number of products. For example a CellPhone.
This CellPhone is sold in numberous shops. Let's call this junction table: cellphone_shop.

```
public class CellPhoneShop {

    public int CellPhoneId;
    public CellPhone CellPhone;

    public int ShopId;
    public Shop Shop;
}
```

In Entity Framework Core I expect to put something like:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<CellPhoneShop>()
             .HasOne(x => x.CellPhone)
             .WithMany(x => x.CellPhoneShops)
             .HasForeignKey(x => x.CellPhoneId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CellPhoneShop>()
             .HasOne(x => x.Shop)
             .WithMany(x => x.CellPhoneShops)
             .HasForeignKey(x => x.ShopId);
```

But imagine the situation that there are two other products. A Laptop and an iPad. 
The Laptop is also sold in numberous shops, the iPad is NOT.

How is it possible to create one junction table ProductShop using Entity framework core?

I started like this:

```
public class ProductShop {

    public int ProductId;
    public Product Product;

    public int ShopId;
    public Shop Shop;
}
```

With the following EF mapping:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductShop>()
       .HasOne(x => x.Shop)
       .WithMany(x => x.ProductShops)
       .HasForeignKey(x => x.ShopId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductShop>()
       .HasOne(x => x.Product)
       .WithMany(??????????)
       .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId);
```

The 'WithMany' property cannot be populated by a 'x.ProductShops' since only the derived members Laptop and CellPhone consist of shops.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A `ProductShop` junction table?

Comment: Ok yes you're right. That's what I actually did but I couldn't figure out how to do this properly in EF core. I updated my question. Maybe it clears up some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a different junction table for every derived type. In hibernate it would do this automatically, in EF Core (3.0) you are still obliged to do this yourself.